# Using structs instead of classes for simple types

Tags: c#, .net, struct, equality

In C# if I use a struct like shown below and do an equality comparison , values of the fields of the struct would be compared and I would get a result true if all the fields have same value.This is the default behaviour.

```
struct PersonStruct
{
    public PersonStruct(string n,int a)
    {
        Name = n;Age = a;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

var p1 = new PersonStruct("Jags", 1);

var p2 = new PersonStruct("Jags", 1);

Console.WriteLine(p1.Equals(p2)); //Return True
```

In case of class same thing would return a value false as it is a reference type.

```
class PersonClass
{
    public PersonClass(string n, int a)
    {
        Name = n; Age = a;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
var pc1 = new PersonClass("Jags", 1);
var pc2 = new PersonClass("Jags", 1);

Console.WriteLine(pc1.Equals(pc2));//Returns False
```

I understand the above concept.My question is considering the above scenario is it a good idea to use structs in such simple cases instead of a class ? I have commonly seen people implement classes in such cases(e.g. simple DTOs) and do all the extra stuff to implement equality operators (such as IEquatable and overridden equals method) .

Is my understanding correct or am I missing something here ?

Comment: The default equality implementation of `System.ValueType` uses reflection and is relatively inefficient. So you should implement `IEquatable<T>` for your structs and classes anyway. It's even more important for structs to avoid the boxing that would occur if calling `object.Equals`.

Comment: You should make your struct immutable, [mutable structs are evil](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid the default implementation of equality for structs. If your structs contain reference type fields (as `PersonStruct` does) then reflection is used to compare corresponding fields for equality, which is relatively slow. You should also implement `IEquatable<T>` for your structs since calling the `object.Equals(object)` method will cause boxing for both the source and argument struct. This will be avoided if the call can be resolved to `IEquatable<PersonStruct>`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole article about this in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx).

✓ CONSIDER defining a struct instead of a class if instances of the type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in other objects.

X AVOID defining a struct unless the type has all of the following characteristics:

- It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.).
- It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
- It is immutable.
- It will not have to be boxed frequently.

**In all other cases, you should define your types as classes.**

Related:

[When do you use a struct instead of a class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/92339/when-do-you-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class)

Comment: Well that is one rule of thumb. There are others, though and imo equally credible. See Bill Wagner's Effective C# ch.2, Item 18, pp104-110! Quote: _The documentation for .NET recommends that you consider the size of a type as a determining factor.. In reality a much better factor is the use of the type.._

Comment: I think the size limit consideration is because structures are passed by value when they are used as arguments and this may cause problem when you have many method call. @TaW